# How Can I Compact This jQuery Code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coding-style, compression

How can I compact the jQuery Code Below?

```
//FIRST CODE
jQuery('.expand-two').click(function(){
    jQuery('.content-two').slideToggle('fast');
});
jQuery('.expand-two').toggle(function() {
jQuery('.content-two').slideDown('slow');
jQuery(this).find("img").css({
    "-webkit-transform": "rotate(90deg)",
    "-moz-transform": "rotate(90deg)",
    "filter": "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1)"
});
}, function() {
jQuery('.content-two').slideUp('slow');
jQuery(this).find("img").css({
    "-webkit-transform": "rotate(0deg)",
    "-moz-transform": "rotate(0deg)",
    "filter": "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0)"
});
});
//SECOND CODE
jQuery('.expand-three').click(function(){
    jQuery('.content-three').slideToggle('fast');
});
jQuery('.expand-three').toggle(function() {
jQuery('.content-three').slideDown('slow');
jQuery(this).find("img").css({
    "-webkit-transform": "rotate(90deg)",
    "-moz-transform": "rotate(90deg)",
    "filter": "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1)"
});
}, function() {
jQuery('.content-three').slideUp('slow');
jQuery(this).find("img").css({
    "-webkit-transform": "rotate(0deg)",
    "-moz-transform": "rotate(0deg)",
    "filter": "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0)"
});
});
```

How would I be able to have multiple DIV Classes plugged into one line? Without having to have so much code for each and every snippet?

Thank you so much!

Comment: `jQuery('.expand-two, .expand-three')` selects both elements.  You can use that to help combine functions.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do with [`.toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)? It doesn't take two function arguments.

Comment: @meagar It's not really documented the way it's being used here but it does work. `.toggle(function () {}, function () {})` will toggle between the two functions.

Comment: @Rocket: But I have multiple instances on a page, when I apply them with commas separating them they all FIRE off when I Toggle one class (selector?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea I see - make some function for element rotating - eg.

```
function setRot( jqElm, angle ) {
    var angleIe = Math.round( angle / 90 );
    jqElm.css({
        "-webkit-transform": "rotate(" + angle + "deg)",
        "-moz-transform": "rotate(" + angle + "deg)",
        "filter": "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation="+ angleIe +")"
    });
}
```

Then in code make this

```
setRot( jQuery(this).find("img"), 90 );
```

Second thing you can do is to use multiple selectors ( if it is possible ) by querying with comma -

```
jQuery('.expand-two, .expand-three' )....
```

Comment: But how could I do that in a sense to where it doesn't FIRE off the code, for all of them? Considering I have multiple instances of this on a page.

Comment: Eh ? this function will modify instances you pass as parameter, and is dimensioned to remove all the rotation setups ( 4 x 5 lines, with function ( 8 + 4 lines )

Comment: If you click on one of them you display all of them.

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery('.expand-two, .expand-three') -
```

which allow to select both and will minimize code.

Comment: The reason I have them as classes instead of IDs because there are multiple instances of this code on a page, and when I tried what you listed above, it Fires off every div connected to this code instead of seperately. Thanks though! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('.expand-two, .expand-three').click(){
   value = $( this ). attr("class");
   value = value.substr(value.indexOf("-"));
   doAnim(value);
}

function doAnim(value){
   $('.expand-'+value).toggle() ... some code
}
```